# wpf custom control: audiowaveform rectangle with selection slider

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, user-controls

I'm working on a c# wpf app in which I want to do something with audio. the irrklang audio library provides me with a pcm decoded 16 bit byte array.

I want to create a timeline control  which shows the waveform along the timeline with an overlaying rectangle which the user can drag and click/drag the left and right side to increase or decrease the selection.

It is used to the trim the audio track. I would like the selected min and max to be databindable, the minimum and maximum value of the total track to be bindable.

To clarify here is an image mockup:

[image]

I'm not asking for a complete control but tips and suggestions on how to tackle this are more than welcome. Perhaps solutions like this already exist but so far I haven't been able to find it.

I think I need to tackle: the control (zooming, panning and changing the selection) and drawing the waveform in the control

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [Audio WaveForm Drawing Using WPF](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/07/audio-waveform-drawing-using-wpf.html).

Something based upon [WaveFileTrimmerControl.xaml](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f067d3f5a443#VoiceRecorder.Core%2fWaveFileTrimmerControl.xaml) would be useful, it uses related controls [PolygonWaveFormControl.xaml](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f067d3f5a443#VoiceRecorder.Core%2fPolygonWaveFormControl.xaml) & [RangeSelectionControl.xaml](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f067d3f5a443#VoiceRecorder.Core%2fRangeSelectionControl.xaml) (links are to the XAML but refer to the CS also). In any case it'd be a good starting point for building a control that exactly meets what you want.

You could  override the render method and use primitives which will give possibly better performance; but like anything related to performance I'd try the above approach first which is almost certainly good enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check out this codeplex project
http://wpfsvl.codeplex.com/